# How to change append value's font-size?

Tags: jquery

Guys i have a text area and if i write more than 5 letter , font size will be changed just for that element.But when i do , all elements size changing.So how to to?

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
 $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');
 
  if(userValue.length > 5 ) {
  $("#writtings").parent().css("font-size", 30);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea  id="textarea" placeholder="Write here!"></textarea>    
 <button id="button">Add</button>
 <div id="writtings"></div>
```

[Here also fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ts5vdsa/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert the style directly to the `p` you are appending, no need to edit it's css later.

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
  if(userValue.length > 5 )
    $('#writtings').append('<p style="font-size:30px">' + userValue + '</p>');
  else
    $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <textarea  id="textarea" placeholder="Write here!"></textarea>    
 <button id="button">Add</button>
 <div id="writtings"></div>
```

Comment: Yea i think about this  but  thought maybe there is another solution , thanks anyway dude!

Comment: What do you need to get?

Answer (score 0):

The parent of the writtings element is the parent of all the new `p` tags. You need to style each paragraph added separately.

e.g.

```
$("#button").click(function() {
  var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
  var newContent = $('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');
 $('#writtings').append(newContent);

  if(userValue.length > 5 ) {
        newContent.css("font-size", 30);
  }
});
```

**JSFiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/4ts5vdsa/2/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify the latest added p tag you could use the last-child selector:

```js
$("#button").click(function() {
  var userValue = $('#textarea').val();
  $('#textarea').val('');
  $('#writtings').append('<p>' + userValue + '</p>');
  
  if(userValue.length > 5 ) {
      $("#writtings p:last-child").css("font-size", 30);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  id="textarea" placeholder="Write here!"></textarea>    
<button id="button">Add</button>
<div id="writtings"></div>
```